# Whether RANK () OVER can give the 'most popular' value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a question whether `RANK () OVER` function can give the 'most popular' value?

Question:

> What route was the most popular of those with an average trip time of at least 8 minutes, excluding trips longer than 2 hours?

Can someone confirm whether `RANK() OVER` satisfies this 'popularity' value?

Comment: tag your database , also provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rank` should be OK; though, I understood the question a little bit differently than you: first restrict all trips to those shorter than 2 hours, and then calculate the rest of data you need. Something like this:

```
select start_station, 
       end_station,
       rank() over (order by cnt desc) rnk
from 
  (select start_station, 
          end_station,
          avg(duration_seconds) avg_duration,
          count(*) cnt
   from tutorial.dc_bikeshare_q1_2012
   where duration_seconds < 7200
   group by start_station, end_station
  ) as x
where avg_duration >= 480;
```

Comment: It says ' subquery in FROM must have an alias'.

Comment: So, add an alias (see edited code).

Comment: I am not sure but it still doesn't work. Now it says 'relation "dc_bikeshare_q1_2012" does not exist'

Comment: Ah; `tutorial.` was missing (along with the table name), sorry, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The question asks for the *one* most popular route. `rank()` would be a waste of time. `ORDER BY` + `LIMIT 1` should be cheaper:

```sql
SELECT start_station, end_station, count(*) AS ct
FROM   tutorial.dc_bikeshare_q1_2012
WHERE  duration_seconds <= 7200
GROUP  BY start_station, end_station
HAVING avg(duration_seconds) >= 480
ORDER  BY ct DESC  -- add more expressions to break ties
LIMIT  1;
```

You are not the only one working on this:

- [Count combination + frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69861089/count-combination-frequency/69861412#69861412)